# Array out of bounds exception:100

Tags: java

This program is giving me array out of bounds exception :100
How to resolve???  also tell me whether my printing method of array is correct or not?

```
    import java.util.Random; 
    import java.lang.Math;    

    class MersennePrime  { 

        public  int[] MersennefindPrime() {     
            int i=0;    
            int k=0;    
            int array[] = new int[100];     
            for(i=2;i<100;i++)    
            {       
                int count=0;          
                for(int j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(i);j++  )          
                {             
                    if(i%j==0)              
                    {                               
                    }                               
                    else                
                    {               
                        array[k]=i;                 
                        k++  ;              
                    }           
                }      
            }       
            return array; 
        }        

    }  


    public class MersenneRandomNumbers  
    {   
        public static void main(String[] args)      
        {                       
            MersennePrime mrn = new MersennePrime();        
            int array[] =mrn.MersennefindPrime();       
            for(int s=0;s<=array.length;s  )        
                System.out.println("array is " array[s]);
            } 
        } 
   }
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
for(int s=0;s<=array.length;s  )        
  System.out.println("array is " array[s]);
}
```

should be like this

```
for(int s=0; s<array.length; s++) {    
  System.out.println( "array is " + array[s] );
}
```

Note the change from `<=` to `<`!

In your code, within the last loop `s` equals `array.length`, which is just the first index outside the boundaries of the array.

**EDIT**

Beside the upper syntactic error, there is a logical one here as well. In `MersennefindPrime()` the outer loop runs from 0 to 100, while the inner loop runs ("worst case") from 2 to 10. So there might be about 10 * 100 times, where you increase `k` and try to set the respective index in the array. This is far more, than the 100 items you allocated the array for!

If you can't be sure about the extent of your array at initialization, use some class, that implements the interface [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). This could then look like this:

```
    public  List<Integer> MersennefindPrime() {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=2;i<100;i++)
        {
            for(int j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(i);j++  )
            {
                if(i%j==0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    array.add( i );
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

<sub>You would have to adjust the code in main() accordingly!</sub>

Comment: There are two more errors in that code. It won't even compile.

Comment: @Jesper You're right. I was just focused on the exception and didn' note the other mistakes. Too much c/p is bad in answers ,-)

Comment: Missing `{` in for loop.

Comment: i did try using s<array.length-1 but the problem still persists .. and there is no compilation error since i have only one line written inside for loop it doesn't matter whether i put braces or not right?

Comment: @Sidarth In your code you have a closing bracket, so you should add the opening bracket. Furthermore, in which line does the error occur?

Comment: error occurs at line number 26 and 46

Comment: in notepad it shown error at above mentioned lines but in n netbeans it shows error on line 32 and 52

Comment: @Sidarth We sorted out your syntactical errors, but for a real prime test, you should revise your logic, too. Just for a test run the inner loop for one iteration of i (e.g., `i == 10`) and have a look at the generated output.

Comment: yess .. maybe i should use count instead

Comment: i have used count and it has resolved the problem but while printing in the main method it prints all the elements upto the array length like indexes for which i have not assigned any value whose dafault value is zero .. i want to avoid that and print upto only that index for which i have assigned a value.. any clue??

Comment: @Sidarth Like I said, your logic is here is completely wrong. Take a step back and revise your approach! Use smaller numbers in the loop and do it **one time by hand**. Your code currently does not find prime numbers.